# Making a simple graph using a slider

Tags: c#

I want to use a slider to create a simple graph containing both the value for Celsius and Fahrenheit and update as I move the slider. Now the graph for Fahrenheit is showing and updates as I move the slider but the graph for Celsius does not show. The slider has a minimum="0" and maximum="100" in XAML. **Targetting WPF**.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** added XAML code + target

**Edit2:** placed updated code underneath original code

```
<Window x:Class="O6._4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:O6._4"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Calculate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Name="CalculateButton" Click="CalculateButton_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Content="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Name="ClearButton" Click="ClearButton_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>

    <Label Content="xxx" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="fahrenheitLabel"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="° Fahrenheit" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,145,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" Name="celsiusSlider" ValueChanged="celsiusSlider_ValueChanged" Minimum="0"  Maximum="100"/>
    <Label Content="xxx" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,168,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="celsiusLabel"/>

    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="250" Margin="220,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" Name="paperCanvas" Background="LightGray"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="250,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="°C" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="315,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="°F" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

```
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private int celsius;
        private int fahrenheit;
        private SolidColorBrush brush;
        private Rectangle rectangle;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        celsiusLabel.Content = Convert.ToString(celsiusSlider.Value);
        fahrenheitLabel.Content = Convert.ToString(32);

        brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

        CreateRectangle(paperCanvas, brush, celsius, 20);
        CreateRectangle(paperCanvas, brush, fahrenheit, 80);
    }

    private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void celsiusSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        celsius = Convert.ToInt32(celsiusSlider.Value);
        celsiusLabel.Content = Convert.ToString(celsius);
        fahrenheit = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
        fahrenheitLabel.Content = Convert.ToString(fahrenheit);
        //UpdateRectangle(celsiusSlider.Value);
        UpdateRectangle(celsius);
        UpdateRectangle(fahrenheit);
    }

    private void CreateRectangle(Canvas drawingArea, SolidColorBrush brush, int temperatureValue, int xPosition)
    {
        rectangle = new Rectangle
        {
            Width = 40,
            Height = temperatureValue,
            Margin = new Thickness(xPosition,0,0,0),
            Stroke = brush,
            Fill = brush,
        };
        drawingArea.Children.Add(rectangle);
    }

    private void UpdateRectangle(double sliderValue)
    {
        rectangle.Height = sliderValue;
    }
}
```

**Updated code**

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private int celsius;
    private int fahrenheit;
    private SolidColorBrush brush;
    private Rectangle celsiusRectangle;
    private Rectangle fahrenheitRectangle;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        celsiusLabel.Content = Convert.ToString(celsiusSlider.Value);
        fahrenheitLabel.Content = Convert.ToString(32);

        brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

        celsiusRectangle = CreateRectangle(paperCanvas, brush, celsius, 20);
        fahrenheitRectangle = CreateRectangle(paperCanvas, brush, fahrenheit, 80);
    }

    private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void celsiusSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        celsius = Convert.ToInt32(celsiusSlider.Value);
        celsiusLabel.Content = Convert.ToString(celsius);
        fahrenheit = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
        fahrenheitLabel.Content = Convert.ToString(fahrenheit);
        UpdateRectangle();
    }

    private Rectangle CreateRectangle(Canvas drawingArea, SolidColorBrush brush, int temperatureValue, int xPosition)
    {
        var rectangle = new Rectangle
        {
            Width = 40,
            Height = temperatureValue,
            Margin = new Thickness(xPosition,0,0,0),
            Stroke = brush,
            Fill = brush,
        };
        drawingArea.Children.Add(rectangle);
        return rectangle;
    }

    private void UpdateRectangle()
    {
        celsiusRectangle.Height = celsius;
        fahrenheitRectangle.Height = fahrenheit;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Silders usage is normally percent based, you would want to assign its min and max values.

Comment: I did: The slider has a minimum="0" and maximum="100" in XAML.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Show your XAML.

Comment: Added the XAML + target.

Comment: @TaW forgot to add users in the reply

Comment: @jsanalytics, forgot to add users in the reply

Comment: It is actually working but your XAML layout is a little messed up. Increase the font size in your labels and you'll see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CreateRectangle` function has issue. Because you only have one `private Rectangle rectangle` variable. Last call `CreateRectangle` override celsus `rectangle` and lost handler. Then only `fahrenheit` rectangle work.

Use 2 `Rectangle` variable and change `CreateRectangle` function

```
private Rectangle CreateRectangle(Canvas drawingArea, SolidColorBrush brush, int temperatureValue, int xPosition)
    {
var rectangle = new Rectangle //<-- Made change here
        {
            Width = 40,
            Height = temperatureValue,
            Margin = new Thickness(xPosition,0,0,0),
            Stroke = brush,
            Fill = brush,
        };
        drawingArea.Children.Add(rectangle);
return rectangle; //<-- Made change here
    }
```

then create using like this

```cs
   celsuiusRectangle= CreateRectangle(paperCanvas, brush, celsius, 20);
   fahrenheitRectangle= CreateRectangle(paperCanvas, brush, fahrenheit, 80);
```

Comment: Thank you for your awnser. I have a couple of questions tho. If I use the var tag before reactangle in the CreateRectangle method wont I get a NullReferenceException in UpdateReactangle as I created 'rectangle' as an instance variable?

I updated the code as you said but still only 1 graph is shown.